# Type annotated tuple pattern in case statement?

Tags: swift

I want to have type-annotated (hence type-constrained, unless I'm misunderstanding) pattern matching, like the following:

```
func F<T1, T2>(_ t: (T1, T2)) {
  switch t {
  case let (x: Int, y: String):
    // do something
  default:
    // do something else
  }
}
```

but I'm obviously doing something wrong since I get a `Tuple pattern element label 'x' must be '_'` compiler error on the `case let (x: Int, y: String):` line.

`case let (x, y):` works but fails to match the types (`x` and `y` bind to any types).

Looking through the grammar in *The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.6 beta),*

```
<case> <pattern>:
<case> <value-binding-pattern>:
<case> let <pattern>:
<case> let <tuple-pattern> <type-annotation opt>:
<case> let (<tuple-pattern-element-list>) <type-annotation opt>:
<case> let (<tuple-pattern-element-list>) <type-annotation opt>:
<case> let (<tuple-pattern-element>, <tuple-pattern-element>) <type-annotation opt>:
<case> let (<tuple-pattern-element>, <tuple-pattern-element>) <type-annotation opt>:
<case> let (<pattern>, <pattern>) <type-annotation opt>:
<case> let (<identifier-pattern>, <identifier-pattern>) <type-annotation opt>:
<case> let (<identifier>, <identifier>) <type-annotation opt>:
...
```

so I feel like it should be ok to say even the following

```
func F<T1, T2>(_ t: (T1, T2)) {
  switch t {
  case let (x, y) : (Int, String):
  ...
```

but all my such attempts fail miserably (do not compile) in one way or another.

What is the right way to do that sort of matching where the tuple item values are bound and I can also constrain the types of the tuple elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
func F<T1, T2>(_ t: (T1, T2)) {
   switch t {
   case let (x, y) as (Int, String):
      // do something
   default:
      // do something else
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  Not really easy to figure from the language reference.

Comment: [too late to edit my first comment]
How would one go about partial type matches?  Is using `Any` the canonical approach here?  As in 
`func F<T1, T2>(_ t: (T1, T2)) {
   switch t {
   case let (x, y) as (Int, String):
      // do something
   case let (x, _) as (Int, Any):
      // do something else
   default:
      // do something else
   }
}`

Comment: @giik You cannot match a partial type. In my opinion you should use the default branch to make a separate `switch` over `t.0` or `t.1`. Note that this kind of dynamic switching over types looks like a bad practice anyway.